# How to call image on css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to call image using img

and this is my code:

```
<img src="/pc/images/leader.png">
```

is this possible to put this in css? like this code:
without using background-image.

css

```
.leader{
  src: /pc/images/leader.png;
}
```

html

```
  <img class="leader">
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You can't do it with css.

CSS has no use of foreground images. You can only use background images.

However, if I understand your problem, you can do place the image using [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after):

```
.leader::after{
   content: "";
   background: url(path.jpg) no-repeat;
   position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 50%;
   height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This is just an example. You can define as you want.

Comment: I guess what I mean is, if you know the dimensions of your image, is there any benefit to not setting a fixed width?

Comment: You can do how you want your layout should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
.leader::after{   
   background: url(path.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;   
}

if you use 50% 50% then the image will be at centre possition.
```